# iOS7 Text chat application with background MultiTasking and without APNS

Tags: ios7, multitasking, nsurlsession

I wish to make chat application that will use background service that will persistently query certain server of clients choice.

This app is chat application.

I am developer of iOS application but I do not own/control these servers.

I can't share my APNS certificate with 3rd parties that control these servers.

So the only way I see to implement it on iOS is to use `MultiTasking API` and `NSURLSession` class.

Is it permitted create chat applications that will not use `APNS` but will use `MultiTasking API`?

Answer (score 0):

take a look at https://github.com/robbiehanson/XMPPFramework. Just declare your app as a voip.

Comment: You may add some example or description so that other can understand.